# In excel, as new cells are added to one column, I would like another cell in another column to copy the most recent addition

Tags: excel, finance

[Screenshot of spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjPTx.png)

I'm doing a mock budget for a class to manage debt.

A summary of all the debts are on the left under "Debt Status."  On the right, I have more detailed columns, each of which monitors a specific debt.

When I add a new payment entry to Medical, I enter the date and payment to J6 and K6.  L6 automatically updates the new balance.  I want the cell in C4 to copy and display the *latest* addition to the column L.

In other words, I don't want to just have a "Total" cell at the bottom, because I don't where the bottom will be.  As the balance goes up and down, the length of the column grows.

I simply want the cell, C4, to grab the *most recent* addition to the entire column L.  In the image, C4 should display "488.00".

Is this possible?

Thanks for reading,

danger_ginger

Answer (score 0):

If the newest value is always at the **bottom** of the column, then:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/(L:L<>""),L:L)
```

[image]

If the newest value is not at the bottom, then we must first find the *MAX()* of column **J** and then use a *MATCH()/INDEX()* based on that.

Comment: It works.  This is exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much!

Comment: @danger_ginger  Thank you for the feedback.